# Alternatives to default copy/move manager

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, filemanager

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and I want to know if there is any other copy/move manager rather than default.

Some features which I would in the copy manager are:

1. auto start as my session start
2. copy and resume options
3. small and lightweight
4. must be a GUI
5. having some features for copy management such as duplicate finder, transfer speed  control, priority

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Ultracopie](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/)

Install

```
sudo apt-get install ultracopier
```

Or

Install [**Ultracopier**](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ultracopier) [image: Install soundconverter]

Ones installed run from the launcher and you will see the icon like this

[image]

Click on the icon and add copy/moving -> add copy

[image]

You will see the dialogbox like this:

Click the plus button and add your copy file or folder (it will asking you the source folder you wish to copy and the destination folder you wish to transfer)

[image]

Ones you did that you will see the copy progress like this:

[image]

You can pause, skip or cancel the progress. and also you will see the copy errors under the `error and log` tab.

Comment: thanks but can you please tell me how to make it as default copier

Comment: it is not practical to click  ultracopier every time and add files and all that.......

Comment: Bay the way once you opened it, it will detect any copy command. I will let you know my full test result.  give me a min :) we can talk here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room